# Google Analytics BigQuery get the time difference between two different pages by user

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the difference in time by user between the first step checkout and final purchase. This is my query:

```
SELECT transactionid1,MAX((t1.hit_moment1-t2.hit_moment2)) as diff_hits,MAX(t2.checkout_step_2) as day  FROM ((SELECT clientId as client1_id,
hits_1.page.pagePath as page_event1,
hits_1.eventInfo.eventAction as action_event1,
hits_1.transaction.transactionId as transactionId1,
TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) as checkout_step_1,
hits_1.hour as hour1,
hits_1.minute as minute1,
(hits_1.hour*60+hits_1.minute) as hit_moment1
from `616180.ga_sessions_*`  ,
UNNEST(hits) as hits_1 where hits_1.page.pagePath like '%/buy1/suscription%' and  hits_1.eventInfo.eventAction="Transaction" and hits_1.transaction.transactionId is not null)t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT clientId as client2_id,
hits_2.page.pagePath as page_event2,
hits_2.eventInfo.eventAction as action_event2,
TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) as checkout_step_2,
hits_2.hour as hour2,
hits_2.minute as minute2,
(hits_2.hour*60+hits_2.minute) as hit_moment2
from `616180.ga_sessions_*` ,UNNEST(hits) as hits_2 where hits_2.page.pagePath like '%/buy4/suscription%' and  hits_2.eventInfo.eventAction="Checkout" )t2 on t1.client1_id=t2.client2_id) where (t1.hit_moment1-t2.hit_moment2)>0 and (t1.hit_moment1-t2.hit_moment2)<180 group by transactionId1 order by transactionid1
```

Where pagePath contains  /buy1/suscription represents the transaction event and pagePath equal to buy4/suscription represents the first checkout step. I get results, but many of them are extremely large periods of time. Have i made a mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully follow what the sample data looks like or exactly the format your want for the result set.

That said, you can use aggregation to do the calculation you want.  The following assumes that the checkout is after the transaction, but it gives the basic idea:

```
select s.transaction_id,
       max(hit.hour * 60 + hit.minutes) - min(hit.hour * 60 + hit.minutes) as diff_minute
from `616180.ga_sessions_*` s cross join
     unnest(s.hits) as hit
where (hit.page.pagePath like '%/buy1/suscription%' and  
       hit.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Transaction' or
      ) or
      (hit.page.pagePath like '%/buy4/suscription%' and   
       hit.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Checkout'
      )
group by s.transaction_id;
```